# Choose top three price points by category in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, top-n

I'm working on a Power BI report, and I have a dataset with a large list of prices broken down by company, product class and product name.  What I'd like to do is display the top three prices in each class, and show which product name, and which company is attributed to that top price.  The dataset looks similar to this:

| Company | Product Class | Product Name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | Class1 | Product 1 | 500 |
| Company A | Class1 | Product 2 | 600 |
| Company A | Class1 | Product 3 | 550 |
| Company A | Class1 | Product 4 | 300 |
| Company A | Class1 | Product 5 | 620 |
| Company A | Class2 | Product A | 50 |
| Company A | Class2 | Product B | 55 |
| Company A | Class2 | Product C | 60 |
| Company A | Class2 | Product D | 40 |
| Company A | Class2 | Product E | 53 |
| Company A | Class3 | Product 10 | 1000 |
| Company A | Class3 | Product 11 | 1100 |
| Company A | Class3 | Product 12 | 1120 |
| Company A | Class3 | Product 13 | 1030 |
| Company A | Class3 | Product 14 | 1080 |

I'd like it to look a bit like this :

| Product Class | Product Name | Company | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class1 | Product 5 | Company A | 620 |
| Class1 | Product 2 | Company A | 600 |
| Class1 | Product 3 | Company A | 550 |
| Class2 | Product C | Company A | 60 |
| Class2 | Product B | Company A | 55 |
| Class2 | Product E | Company A | 53 |
| Class3 | Product 12 | Company A | 1120 |
| Class3 | Product 11 | Company A | 1100 |
| Class3 | Product 14 | Company A | 1080 |

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to have a measure check, if the product is in the top 3 and return blank, if it's not. Then you put the measure in the visual level filter and select `Is not blank`. The measure could look like this:

```
Is top product =
IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Table[Product Name] )
        IN SELECTCOLUMNS (
            TOPN (
                3,
                CALCULATETABLE ( Table, REMOVEFILTERS ( Table[Product Name] ) ),
                [Price]
            ),
            "Product Name", [Product Name]
        ),
    1,
    BLANK ()
)
```

[image]